# PYQT5 Open menu on cursor position in QTextEditor

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QTextEditor which I would like to open a menu for user to choose when he press Ctrl+Space.
I was able to capture the key events and create the menu and trigger it.

My problem is to open the menu on the text cursor position.
How do i get the QPoint of the textcursor and not the mouse position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTextEdit.cursorRect` returns a rectangle (in viewport coordinates) that includes the cursor.

You're probably imlementing autocompletion/intellisense, it which case I'd recommend using `QCompleter` instead of `QMenu`. Take a look at [Custom Completer Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html).

You can override `QTextEdit.keyPressEvent` or use eventFilter to capture Ctrl+Space shortcuts and call `completer.complete(rect)` to show popup.

Comment: It's more like templates insertions than word completion. Your suggestion works 100%, thanks :)